# Looking for someway to fix this 'size' is not defined error in pygame basketball sim?

Tags: python, python-3.x, debugging, pygame, runtime-error

**I know the code is a bit flawed but its a simple prototype for a project im doing, below I have given the code and the error that occurs to do with size:**

*So the "teams" parent class will potentially hold many teams, allowing a different number of players (PlayerSet) and a team selection (startTeam). "Players" is a subclass of "teams" which will generate circles to represent players and the circles will be a set rgb colour relative to the team (Cavaliers Wine and Golden State Yellow) ---- in the future/my real code the circles will hold a player number inside. Sidenote: I know there's better ways to do this but I have to make it complex in order to get a good grade :D*

```
import pygame
pygame.init()

(width, height) = (940,500)
screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) 
pygame.display.set_caption('Basketball Simulator')
background_image = pygame.image.load("bballcourt.jpg")

class teams():

    def __init__(self, teamname = "unknown", numPlayers = "5", wins = "0", losses = "0"):
        self.teamname = teamname
        self.numPlayers = numPlayers
        self.wins = wins
        self.losses = losses

    def startTeam(self):
        self.teamname = input("Please select a team // GSW or CAVS: ")
        validTeam = False
        while validTeam == False:
            if self.teamname.upper() == "GSW":
                self.teamname = ("Golden State Warriors")
                validTeam = True
            elif self.teamname.upper() == "CAVS":
                self.teamname = ("Cleveland Cavaliers")
                validTeam = True
            else:
                validTeam = False
    def playerSet(self,teamname):
        if self.teamname == ("Cleveland Cavaliers"):
            self.numPlayers = ("5")
        else:
            self.numPlayers = ("5")

class Player(teams):
    def __init__ (self):
        super().__init__(size, (x,y), colour, thickness)
        self.size = size
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.colour = (0,0,0)
        self.thickness = 0
        

    def teamColour(self,teamname):
        if self.teamname == ("Cleveland Cavaliers"):
            self.colour = (134,0,56)
        elif self.teamname == ("Golden State Warriors"):
            self.colour = (0,107,182)
        else:
            self.colour = (255,255,255)
    def display(self):
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, self.colour, (self.x, self.y), self.size, self.thickness)

screen.blit(background_image, [0,0]) 
#myPlayer1 = Player()
myPlayer1 = Player()
myPlayer1.startTeam()
myPlayer1.teamColour()
myPlayer1.display([300, 300],15)      
pygame.display.flip()

running = True
while running:
   for event in pygame.event.get():
       if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
           running = False
           pygame.quit()
           quit
```

ERROR:

```
line 37, in __init__
    super().__init__(size, (x,y), colour, thickness)
NameError: name 'size' is not defined

line 57, in <module>
    myPlayer1 = Player()
```

Comment: Even if you fixed that, you would have the same problem with x, y, colour and thickness. You need to think about where those values are supposed to be coming from. Also, why are you passing them to the superclass anyway? `teams` does not expect them. And yet again, why does Player inherit from teams? A player is not a type of team.

Comment: I understand my main issue now thank you. I was told I had to make it compelx, otherwise my intended method was to use dictionaries and then list players as in this link: http://nbviewer.jupyter.org/github/pybokeh/ipython_notebooks/blob/master/web_scraping/NBA_Player_Stats.ipynb

Comment: I assume your suggesting a similar idea of having them as seperate classes. My bad, I thought it would be complex but all the kids in my senior class are mad now ;D apparently this is exponentially harder to get to work than neccesary. Thanks Daniel.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few error's in your code

1.

```
    import pygame
    pygame.init()

    (width, height) = (940,500)
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode((width, height)) 
    pygame.display.set_caption('Basketball Simulator')
    background_image = pygame.image.load("bballcourt.jpg")

    class teams():

        def __init__(self, teamname = "unknown", numPlayers = "5", wins = "0", losses = "0"):
            self.teamname = teamname
            self.numPlayers = numPlayers
            self.wins = wins
            self.losses = losses

        def startTeam(self):
            self.teamname = input("Please select a team // GSW or CAVS: ")
            validTeam = False
            while validTeam == False:
                if self.teamname.upper() == "GSW":
                    self.teamname = ("Golden State Warriors")
                    validTeam = True
                elif self.teamname.upper() == "CAVS":
                    self.teamname = ("Cleveland Cavaliers")
                    validTeam = True
                else:
                    validTeam = False
        def playerSet(self,teamname):
            if self.teamname == ("Cleveland Cavaliers"):
                self.numPlayers = ("5")
            else:
                self.numPlayers = ("5")

    class Player(teams):
        def __init__ (self):
            super().__init__()

            self.colour = (0,0,0)
            
            

        def teamColour(self):
            if self.teamname == ("Cleveland Cavaliers"):
                self.colour = (134,0,56)
            elif self.teamname == ("Golden State Warriors"):
                self.colour = (0,107,182)
            else:
                self.colour = (255,255,255)
        def display(self,size, x,y, colour, thickness):
            pygame.draw.circle(screen,colour, (x, y), size, thickness)

    screen.blit(background_image, [0,0]) 
    #myPlayer1 = Player()
    myPlayer1 = Player()
    myPlayer1.startTeam()
    myPlayer1.teamColour()
    myPlayer1.display(50,300, 300,pygame.Color('red'),15)      
    pygame.display.flip()

    running = True
    while running:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            running = False
            pygame.quit()
            quit
```

this is the corrected code.

Comment: Please tell which part of the code is wrong with commend # and explained why your work

Comment: Someone has changed your code to the same one as mine. I am not able to remember all the changes

Comment: Thank you to whoever answered - I will take a look at the changes soon. This question was posted when I was a Senior in HS and now i'm about to graduate and have solid industry experience. I can't wait to laugh at whatever the question is asking :D